# How can i use SQL Developer exporter for MS Access

Tags: xml, oracle-sqldeveloper, ms-access-2013

I am trying to export ms access data into XML file using SQl Developer exporter function.

I don't see Migration Menu > Microsoft Access Exporter on SQL developer screen.

Please see the screenshot attached.[Sql developer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4eQc.png)

Comment: Why not use MS Access to export MS Access data to XML?

Comment: I do see the Microsoft Access Exporter on your screenshot... so what do you mean?

Comment: @Alex  - that screenshot is from one of the documents showing how to use exporter function.

Comment: Well perhaps you should make that clear in your question, and include a link to that document, not least to show attribution for the image? Are you trying to do this on a PC [that has MS Access installed](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RPTUG/migration.htm#i1005890) too? And which version of SQL Developer are you using? (The [4,1 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55747_01/appdev.41/e55591/migrating-third-party-databases.htm#migration) don't seem to refer to Access, interestingly)

Comment: @ Parfait - how can i do that?

Comment: @ Alex - http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/msaccess/viewlets/access_capture.html

Comment: @ Alex - yes i have ms access 2013 installed. Also i have SQL developer 4.1 and here is the link that i am following http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/msaccess/migrate_microsoft_access_otn.htm                          and i am stuck on the step Capturing the Microsoft Access Exported XML

Comment: @Parfait - i can only import one table a time. as soon as i select all the Access tables XML import option is disabled.

Comment: You can use scripting code to automate all tables using Access's [ExportXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193212.aspx) method

Comment: @ Parfait - i have not done that before but i will try to find out thanks for your help!!